# Rotate an image in Android instantly (or almost)

Tags: android, codenameone

I develop with Codename One and know how to rotate an image.

The problem is that the rotation of a photograph as returned by the camera or gallery (i.e. at maximum resolution) takes a variable time (about 5 seconds or more) on my Samsung Galaxy A20 (Android 10).

When I talk about rotations, I always refer to rotations of 90 degrees or multiples of 90 degrees.

I hope there are more efficient ways to rotate a high resolution image, e.g. by having the GPU do the work rather than the CPU. That's why I ask you Android programmers: do you have a code that can rotate a high-resolution image instantly or almost instantly?

As regards Codename One, for those who don't know it, it is possible to use native Android code, that's why I'm addressing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which image type?

If it's `EncodedImage` try to make it into a regular image first or at least `lock()` it. It's possible that the GC is thrashing the image out of RAM and you get repeated decode cycles. A 90 degree rotation should be pretty fast on a powerful device like that even for a very large image.

So something like this should be pretty fast:

```
img.lock();
Image rotated; 
switch(degrees)) {
   case 90: 
      rotated = img.rotate90Degrees();
      break;
   case 180: 
      rotated = img.rotate180Degrees();
      break;
   case 270: 
      rotated = img.rotate270Degrees();
      break;
   default: 
      rotated = img.rotate(degrees);
      break;
}
img.unlock();
```

I suggest benchmarking this if this takes too long to figure the exact method that takes up CPU time. This should all perform very fast.

Comment: Wow!!!! Thanks to `lock` and `unlock` the rotation is now incredibly fast, practically instantaneous!!! This is a problem I've had forever, practically since I've known Codename One. Specifically, then the https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#exifRotation-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- implementation needs to be changed so that this method works instantly instead of making me wait the usual five seconds and more with high resolution images.

Comment: Why aren’t lock and unlock invoked implicitly when rotating an image? Do lock and unlock are useful to boost the performace of every image manipulation?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense for this use case. The answer is that no one asked for that and image locking is a complex subject...